# Function to find check non-null form control values recursively in a FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I want to create a function that can check if there is at least one non-null value in a `FormGroup` which can consist of any type of `AbstractControl` (`FormControl`, `FormArray` or `FormGroup`). All the values are set to `null` by default. I've come across a function to count all the `FormControl` in a `FormGroup` recursively.

```js
const countControls = (control: AbstractControl): number => {
  if (control instanceof FormControl) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (control instanceof FormArray) {
    return control.controls.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + countControls(curr), 1)
  }

  if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
    return Object.keys(control.controls)
      .map(key => control.controls[key])
      .reduce((acc, curr) => acc + countControls(curr), 1);
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/recursively-count-form-controls)

I haven't been able to convert this function for my use-case(i.e. checkNonNull) which would return a boolean. true for at least one non-null value and false otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Same process but looking for form controls with a value and returning true if any.

```
const checkNonNull = (control: AbstractControl): boolean => {
  if (control instanceof FormControl) {
    return control.value ? true : false;
  }

  if (control instanceof FormArray) {
    return control.controls.some((ctrl) => checkNonNull(ctrl));
  }

  if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
    return Object.keys(control.controls)
      .map((key) => checkNonNull(control.controls[key])).some(result => result == true);
  }
};
```